# *ngIf si encuentra un valor en un array angular 4

Tags: angular4, angular-directivas, angular2-template, angular5

como puedo hacer el ngIf con la condicion de que muestre el elemento si encuentra un elemento en un array, ya sea una cadena o un string,

no ecnuentro nada en internet

he intentado 
*nfIf="userModel.roles.find(x => x.name == 'administrator')"
error , error y error, no encuentro como resolver este gran problema, llevo bastante rato .

el modelo user que tengo es

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public email: string,
        public password: string,
        public name: string,
        public roles: Array<any>,
        public permissions: Array<any>,

    ){



    }
}
```

y sin embargo al poner 
// Propiedad calculada en el Modelo
get isAdmin(): boolean {
    this.roles.findIndex(role => role.name === 'administrator') > -1;
  }
me salen errores  como en isAdmin

ademas usando eso como metodo en el componente tampoco functiona

```
checkRoles(){
    if(this.userModel.roles.findIndex(role => role.name === 'administrator') > -1){
      this.isAdmin = true;
    }
  }
```

inicialmente isAdmin esta en falso. Probaste eso en angular 4 o 5?

un ejemplo es nada mas ocultar este menu dependiendo del rol del usuario(puede tener varios roles)

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                Usuarios
              </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/users']">Ver usuarios</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['/users/add']">Agregar usuario</a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

solo quiero ocultarlo si de los roles que tiene el usuario tiene almenos administrador sino que no lo muestre. ese es el ejemplo

Comment: tal vez deberías de poner un [mcve] para tener mejores respuestas

Comment: listo, ya puse el ejemplo de lo que realmente necesito

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es una propiedad calculada en la clase/modelo User, en vez de tu lógica de negocio en la vista, en la vista debe de llegar "todo mascado".

```
// Propiedad calculada en el Modelo
get isAdmin(): boolean {
  this.roles.findIndex(role => role.name === 'administrator') > -1;
}
// En tu Vista
*ngIf="userModel.isAdmin"
```

Comment: pregunta. al usar eso en el modelo me tira errores. el modelo user lo tengo asi

Comment: export class User{
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public email: string,
        public password: string,
        public name: string,
        public roles: Array<any>,
        public permissions: Array<any>,
        
    ){

        

    }
}

Comment: lo segundo es que si lo uso como un metodo el finIdex no reconoce el rol,